# How to implement a function that adds to a class' string and another function that returns it in php?

Tags: php

I am working on this problem:

The user interface contains two types of user input controls: TextInput, which accepts all texts and NumericInput, which accepts only digits.

Implement the class TextInput that contains:

Public function add($text) - adds the given text to the current value.
Public function getValue() - returns the current value (string).

Implement the class NumericInput that:

Inherits from TextInput.
Overrides the add method so that each non-numeric text is ignored.
For example, the following code should output '10':

```
$input = new NumericInput();
$input->add('1');
$input->add('a');
$input->add('0');
echo $input->getValue();
```

Now, I thought the following would be sufficent enough to implement the TextInput class as a minimum as the instructions say

```
class TextInput
{    
    private $str = '';

    public function add($text) {
        $str .= $text;
    }
    public function getValue() {
        return $str;
    }
}

class NumericInput extends TextInput
{

    public function add($text) {
        if ( is_numeric($text)) {
            $str .= $text;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working but I thought at the very least the part for class TextInput was done correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`$str` is just a local variable; in your code, it exists only within the scope of a given method. You want to use the class property that you declared with `private $str...`. That is, you need to refer to the property `$str` of the object using `$this->str`.

In addition to that, a `private` property is not accessible in a child class. That is, instances of `NumericInput` will not have access to the `$str` property of `TextInput`. It would be better to make that property `protected`, rather than `private`.

Your classes should look like:

```
class TextInput
{    
    protected $str = '';

    public function add($text) {
        $this->str .= $text;
    }
    public function getValue() {
        return $this->str;
    }
}

class NumericInput extends TextInput
{

    public function add($text) {
        if ( is_numeric($text)) {
            $this->str .= $text;
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more in [the documentation about properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and [the documentation about visibility](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).